# Cannot append data to file

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to create a file, save data and then append some information to it (ex. the next time app will be started). I'm using this code:

```
       IsolatedStorageFile myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
       using (var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("history.dat", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, myStore))
       {
            //Write the data
            using (var isoFileWriter = new StreamWriter(isoFileStream))
            {
                isoFileWriter.WriteLine(m.Author + "|" + m.Receiver + "|" + m.Text + "|" + m.Date + "\r\n");
            }
       }
```

But it doesn't work :/ Only first line is saved - anything I want to add to the created file is going to nowhere o_O I also tried this approach:

```
            using (var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("history.dat", FileMode.Open, myStore))
            {
                // Read the data.
                using (var isoFileReader = new StreamReader(isoFileStream))
                {
                    data = isoFileReader.ReadLine();
                }
            }
```

To verify the file I have used another class and IsoStoreSpy application.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appending works fine using your code. But for reading all lines you have to iterate them, otherwise you read just the first line:

```
while (!isoFileReader.EndOfStream)
{
    string line = isoFileReader.ReadLine();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Tested and works. And you don't need to append the new line ("\r\n") when writing a line. `WriteLine` will do this for you.

Comment: Still doesnt work! Saving data is the problem - not reading them ( I use also external appication to read data). Only first line (which is writed when file is being created) is saved. o_O Its strange.

Comment: I used exactly your code - appending works, the data is saved across different program starts. Don't know what's different in your project.

Comment: Hmm maybe its the emulator fault? Unfortunately i don't owe WP7 device :/ Ok good to know that this code is okay - I will make some more tests.

Comment: I figured it out ;) Thanks for providing tips :)